# How to read .amr files with python?

Tags: python, amr

Is there a way of reading AMR (audio) files with python?

Are there python modules ready for this task?
Or do i have to parse the AMR as a binary file?

I have been trying to search online with no successes.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572755/encode-decode-amr

Comment: You want to read it and then do what with it? If you want to extract metadata, take a look at the `mutagen` library. If you want to transcode to another audio format, you can use `subprocess` to call `ffmpeg` / `avconv`.  If you want examples of the latter, check the source code https://github.com/dopstar/ftransc . I wrote it myself.

Comment: I want to extract the audio samples  and the sample rate.  Let's say i want to play the file. All in need is the sample of the sound and the sampling rate. So i want to extract those two elements from the file.

Comment: Anyone can tell me how to extract the voice samples and sampling frequency?

Comment: any one with the solution?